# Написание без кавычек слов в необычном значении

Tags: кавычки

Иногда мы интуитивно используем слова в значении (переносном, метафорическом), которого нет в словаре, и не ставим кавычки:

*Тот век **дал** нам таких великих писателей, как Толстой и Достоевский.*

***Выйти** на ежемесячный доход N тыс. руб*.

Почему так?

Моё предположение. [На "Грамоте"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1) есть две рекомендации:

> Чем же все-таки руководствоваться при ответе на вопрос о постановке кавычек? Вот два нехитрых правила:
>
> — ориентироваться на словарные статьи в толковых словарях русского языка: если слово (словосочетание) в них уже зафиксировано, следовательно, значение не является непривычным и кавычки не нужны;
>
> — учитывать стиль текста, в котором встречаются подобные лексические единицы. Безусловно, наиболее часто их можно встретить в газетных и журнальных текстах, но при этом в «серьезных» СМИ, предлагающих читателям материалы на общественно-политические и социально значимые темы, постановка кавычек при необычно употребляемых словах более уместна, чем, например, в газетах и журналах, ориентированных на молодежную аудиторию и пишущих на «легкие» темы, поскольку при употреблении слова в «непривычном» значении оно чаще имеет разговорную или просторечную окраску.

В нашем случае нужно применять вторую рекомендацию: слова "дал" и "выйти" в приведённых предложениях *имеют разговорную или просторечную окраску* и нет необходимости особо подчёркивать необычность их значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словосочетания в приведенных примерах не являются необычными (не требуют кавычек), а также не имеют разговорного или просторечного значения.

1) **Выйти на ежемесячный доход N тыс. руб.**

Выйти на поляну – **пространственное** значение предлога НА (В.п).

Выйти на уровень (чего?) – **предметное** значение предлога НА (В.п).

Выйти на уровень дохода, выйти на доход – это **упрощение** синтаксической конструкции, но сочетание используется в книжной речи, в публицистике например.

Здесь нет необычности употребления, нет разговорного и уж тем более просторечного оттенка.

Сравнить: *Зверь вышел на охотника* (предмет как ориентир). *Он вышел на депутата.* Здесь переносное значение, но словосочетание уже есть в словарной статье  и отмечено **как разг**.

И лишь тогда можно будет **выйти на уровень** простого воспроизводства населения. [Б. Руденко. Исчезающая Россия. Заметки со всероссийской конференции по демографии // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

Как выйти на пассивный доход 100000 рублей в месяц?

2) **Тот век дал нам таких великих писателей, как Толстой и Достоевский.**

ДАТЬ, 1. (кому-чему) кого-что. Передать из рук в руки; вручить. Д. денег на дорогу.

Это первое (прямое) значение многозначного глагола. Можно сказать: *Бог дал ему талант.* Далее идет **развитие переносных значений,** причем все они не являются необычными и  не считаются разговорными или просторечными. **Они существуют на уровне метафор,** и это примеры книжной (публицистической или художественной) речи.

Много славных имен дал миру этот **род** ― педагоги, инженеры, изобретатели, ученые, врачи. **Год** двух Олимпиад дал миру множество знаменитых спортсменов. **Университет** дал миру несколько нобелевских лауреатов.

Приложение: **О лексике разговорной и просторечной**

Сниженная лексика по степени экспрессивно-стилистической окраски делится на два разряда: лексику разговорную и лексику просторечную. В толковых словарях слова этих двух групп снабжаются стилистическими пометами «разг.» и «прост.».

**Эмоционально‑экспрессивная лексика** наиболее полно представлена в разговорно‑обиходной речи, которая отличается живостью и меткостью изложения.  В разговорной речи употребляется преимущественно разговорная лексика, которая **не нарушает общепринятых норм** литературной речи (читалка, препод, – вместо читальный зал, преподаватель). **Разговорные слова противопоставлены книжной лексике.**

https://studfiles.net/preview/1462150/page:9/

Просторечная лексика, отличаясь от разговорной большей силой экспрессии, употребительна главным образом в **эмоциональных речевых ситуациях**, при необходимости дать оценку называемому лицу, свойству, явлению, при дружеских и фамильярных отношениях между собеседниками (использование этой лексики в общении с незнакомым человеком является нарушением не только литературных, но и культурных норм, принятых в данном обществе).

https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/snijennaya-leksika-137540.html

Comment: Sharon, а разве прямое значение сюда подходит?

Comment: Серж, мне кажется, что метафоры как таковой здесь нет. Это грамматический вариант для основного значения глагола, просто действие касается отвлеченных, а не конкретных предметов. Выйти на новый уровень - вполне обычное сочетание, выйти на доход - также часто применяется. Век дал великих писателей - всё в рамках грамматики,  а обобщенные понятия на месте конкретных - это тоже  обычная практика.

Comment: 2) *Далее идет развитие переносных значений, причем все они не являются необычными и не считаются разговорными или просторечными. Они существуют на уровне метафор, и это примеры книжной (публицистической или художественной) речи.* Только это развитие переносных значений не зафиксировано в толковых словарях, а метафоры — во фразеологических.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если автор использует любое слово в переносном/метафорическом значении, которого нет в словарях, и при этом не нужно особо выделять необычность такого значения, то кавычки не нужны?

Comment: Художественные  метафоры не выделяются кавычками, а языковые метафоры должны быть понятными для той аудитории, к которой Вы обращаетесь. Ведь новое значение слова далеко не сразу попадает в словарь, а сначала закрепляется на практике. Автор может проверить, употребляется ли слово  в текстах, как оно там пишется,  а потом принять решение. Здесь требуется языковое чутье. Когда редактируешь текст, то решение о постановке кавычек - это довольно ответственное решение. Кавычки позволяют довольно свободно обращаться с языковым материалом, в то время как их отсутствие может  быть зачтено за ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Примеры, которые вы приводите, как раз относятся к приведенным вами двум пунктом.

Тот век дал нам таких великих писателей, как Толстой и Достоевский. В этом примере глагол "дать" имеет разговорный оттенок.

А втором примере у глагола **"выйти"** переносное значение уже зафиксировано словарями.
Выйти — 4. Достичь какого-л. положения, состояния; стать кем-л., каким-л. *В. в начальники. В. в передовики, в отличники. В. победителем. В. окрепшим, более терпимым из чего-л. В. в люди (достичь хорошего общественного положения). В. замуж за кого-л. (стать чьей-л. женой).* **В. на пенсию, в отставку**. В. в трубку (образовать стебель; о злаках)

Comment: Да, видел это словарное значение для глагола "выйти". Мне кажется, оно не совсем подходит. А вот наличие разговорного оттенка и отсутствие необходимости подчёркивать «необычность» значения здесь на лицо.

Answer (score 0):

Например. Прошёл год. Глагол "прошёл" вполне естественно понимаем. А вот поставим вместо него другой глагол: "отстучал год", "испарился год", "отлежался год"... Что это? Жаргонизмы, сленг, замена глаголу "прошёл"? Авторская отсебятина. 
Наверное, кавычки уместны при авторской отсебятине. 
Лично я использую при переносном смысле одиночные кавычки, а "лапки" и "ёлочки" использую в других случаях. А иногда (но совсем редко) для показания переносного смысла использую курсив.

Comment: Для глагола «прошёл» в словаре зафиксировано  нужное нам значение. А вот для «отстучал», «испарился», «отлежался» — нет. И вопрос именно в том, что, когда значение не зафиксировано, когда это «авторская отсебятина», нужны кавычки или нет? Оказывается, иногда да, а иногда нет — в зависимости от того, нужно ли подчеркивать «необычность» значения. Я это понял так.

Comment: Да, подчёркивание необычности употребления слова и показание на то, чтобы смысл связывали по-авторски (так, как закладывает автор, который искусственно искажает указание на понятие).